# How to create 2 nested tabs within a tab in android?

Tags: android

I have 3 tabs basically and on clicking one of those I want to display 2 more tabs which is like nested tabs. How can I achieve this in android? I just added 3 tabs in an activity and in one tab activity I again added 2 more tabs. But this is giving me error.

Please anybody have any other idea share it and help me out,thanks in advance.

[image: I want the tab as shown in the image below]

Comment: Well how do you imagine that this would work or more specifically look like? When you say tabs I assume you mean tabs in the ActionBar. Where do you want your additional nested tabs to be displayed?

Comment: what do you mean by tabs in action bar?? I have taken the tab widget and added 3 tabs.and now I want to add child tab to one of these 3 tabs...

Comment: Well what do you mean by child tabs? You have to give us more information. Like this you just leave us guessing about your problem. Show us your layout or relevant bits of code. Explain exactly what isn't working.

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694096) answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good idea. How users are supposed to know which tabs would respond to a swipe action? Multi-level tabs are confusing. You should use [drop down navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) or a [navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) instead of top-level tabs.